# Python pandas: output dataframe to csv with integers

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` that I wish to export to a CSV file. However, pandas seems to write some of the values as `float` instead of `int` types. I couldn't not find how to change this behavior.

Building a data frame:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c','d'], index=['x','y','z'], dtype=int)
x = pandas.Series([10,10,10], index=['a','b','d'], dtype=int)
y = pandas.Series([1,5,2,3], index=['a','b','c','d'], dtype=int)
z = pandas.Series([1,2,3,4], index=['a','b','c','d'], dtype=int)
df.loc['x']=x; df.loc['y']=y; df.loc['z']=z
```

View it:

```
>>> df
    a   b    c   d
x  10  10  NaN  10
y   1   5    2   3
z   1   2    3   4
```

Export it:

```
>>> df.to_csv('test.csv', sep='\t', na_rep='0', dtype=int)
>>> for l in open('test.csv'): print l.strip('\n')
        a       b       c       d
x       10.0    10.0    0       10.0
y       1       5       2       3
z       1       2       3       4
```

Why do the tens have a dot zero ?

Sure, I could just stick this function into my pipeline to reconvert the whole CSV file, but it seems unnecessary:

```
def lines_as_integer(path):
    handle = open(path)
    yield handle.next()
    for line in handle:
        line = line.split()
        label = line[0]
        values = map(float, line[1:])
        values = map(int, values)
        yield label + '\t' + '\t'.join(map(str,values)) + '\n'
handle = open(path_table_int, 'w')
handle.writelines(lines_as_integer(path_table_float))
handle.close()
```

Comment: you should `import pandas as pd` :)

Comment: @Andy Why should I do that ? Namespaces are a great idea... until you abbreviate them all and it becomes unreadable.

Comment: That's the standard, similarly numpy is np (and available as pd.np). pandas is significantly longer than pd, writing it out each time would make code *less* readable IMO.

Comment: @AndyHayden Longer to type, but definitely easier to read. To a novice stumbling on the code, `pd` signifies Police Department. Or worse if he speaks french.

Comment: It's just a convention - use it, or don't use it - depends on the expectation of who your audience is likely to be - For many pandas users, the convention is to use pd, just as in the UK, the convention is to drive on the left. It's not a problem until you have to share the same stretch of road.

Comment: I don't think that analogy is adequate, because driving on the left is incompatible with driving on the right. However, using the full package name works fine for a veteran that knows about the abbreviation standard, while the opposite is not true (a novice is baffled by `pd`).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer I was looking for was a slight variation of what @Jeff proposed in his answer. The credit goes to him. This is what solved my problem in the end for reference:

```py
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['a','b','c','d'], index=['x','y','z'])
df = df.fillna(0)
df = df.astype(int)
df.to_csv('test.csv', sep='\t')
```

Comment: This gets around having any floats but you lose the NaN info. Perhaps fill NA with -9999 or some value that you know is not 'real' in your data set.

Comment: you may refer to my answer below to preserve NaN

Comment: How to do that only for one column? My `df` has mixed types, strings and numbers.

Comment: if your data are natural numbers (nonnegative integers), using `df.fillna(-1)` is an option.

Answer (score 18):

This is a ["gotcha" in pandas (Support for integer NA)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na), where integer columns with NaNs are converted to floats.

> This trade-off is made largely for memory and performance reasons, and also so that the resulting Series continues to be “numeric”. One possibility is to use `dtype=object` arrays instead.

Comment: So no way to get them as integers without reparsing the whole file ? How about if I use `df.fillna()` ?

Comment: Use `dtype=object` (rather than `int`) when creating `x` and `df`.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that since you are assigning things by rows, but dtypes are grouped by columns, so things get cast to `object` dtype, which is not a good thing, you lose all efficiency. So one way is to convert which will coerce to float/int dtype as needed.

As we answered in another question, if you construct the frame all at once (or construct column by column) this step will not be needed

```
In [23]: def convert(x):
   ....:     try:
   ....:         return x.astype(int)
   ....:     except:
   ....:         return x
   ....:     

In [24]: df.apply(convert)
Out[24]: 
    a   b   c   d
x  10  10 NaN  10
y   1   5   2   3
z   1   2   3   4

In [25]: df.apply(convert).dtypes
Out[25]: 
a      int64
b      int64
c    float64
d      int64
dtype: object

In [26]: df.apply(convert).to_csv('test.csv')

In [27]: !cat test.csv
,a,b,c,d
x,10,10,,10
y,1,5,2.0,3
z,1,2,3.0,4
```

Comment: But then there is `.0`s in the `c` columns... :s

Comment: because its a float! no choice there (well you CAN pass ``float_format='%.0f'`` to ``to_csv`` but that is could lead to loss of precision –

Comment: But but..., if you use dtype=object (e.g. in x and df via OP's construction, which I agree is not best way) then 2, 3 and 10s are all ints... it's almost always not worth worrying about anyway. This seems just like the transpose of OP's effort :s

Comment: yep...keep stressing that having ``object`` dtype for numbers is bad....maybe we should put in a PerformanceWarning if that occurs (e.g. like in this case)....

Comment: If they have gone out of their way to *choose* dtype=object though, surely they deserve what they get (if they don't they'd get a float). A better solution would for numpy to support NaNs in integer arrays... ;)

Comment: I'm happy with having zeros instead of NaN. Can I get the performance and convenience then by avoiding `dtype=object` and using some combination of `df.fillna(value=0)` and conversion back to integers ?

Comment: if you want to fill like you are filling, check the ``df.dtypes``; you can do ``df.convert_objects()`` to auto convert to floats most likely, then you can ``astype`` if you want. You can ``fillna`` if you really want. The question is why does it matter? (remmeber you can always specify dtypes with ``read_csv``), and why do you *need* integers?

Comment: I need integers because that CSV file is being exported to be read by some other component further down the pipeline. That other component was written long ago by someone else in an other language and doesn't like to have floats as inputs.

Comment: then ``convert_objects().fillna(0).astype(int).to_csv(path)`` should work for you

Comment: As of v0.17, convert_objects is deprecated.

Comment: This was the case for me. I used list comprehension for the int part and just appended the floats and strings later

Answer (score 8):

If you want to preserve NaN info in the csv which you have exported, then do the below.
P.S : I'm concentrating on column 'C' in this case.

```
df[c] = df[c].fillna('')       #filling Nan with empty string
df[c] = df[c].astype(str)      #convert the column to string 
>>> df
    a   b    c     d
x  10  10         10
y   1   5    2.0   3
z   1   2    3.0   4

df[c] = df[c].str.split('.')   #split the float value into list based on '.'
>>> df
        a   b    c          d
    x  10  10   ['']       10
    y   1   5   ['2','0']   3
    z   1   2   ['3','0']   4

df[c] = df[c].str[0]            #select 1st element from the list
>>> df
    a   b    c   d
x  10  10       10
y   1   5    2   3
z   1   2    3   4
```

Now, if you export the dataframe to csv, Column 'c' will not have float values and the NaN info is preserved.

Comment: This solution is nice, but it supposes you know in which column you have missing data, which is rarely the case.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest solution is to use `float_format` in `pd.read_csv()`:

```
df.to_csv('test.csv', sep='\t', na_rep=0, float_format='%.0f')
```

But this applies to *all* float columns. BTW: Using your code on pandas 1.1.5, all of my columns are float.

Output:

```
    a   b   c   d
x   10  10  0   10
y   1   5   2   3
z   1   2   3   4
```

Without `float_format`:

```
    a   b   c   d
x   10.0    10.0    0    10.0
y    1.0     5.0    2.0   3.0
z    1.0     2.0    3.0   4.0
```

Comment: This is by far the best and most precise answer, it does exactly what was asked for in the question. Should get more upvotes. Solved my (same) problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use astype() to specify data type for each column

For example:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['a','b','c','d'], index=['x','y','z'])

df = df.astype({"a": int, "b": complex, "c" : float, "d" : int})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write it out as string to csv:

```
df.to_csv('test.csv', sep='\t', na_rep='0', dtype=str)
```

Comment: It does not work at all. TypeError: to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'

Comment: if it doesn't work, use astype() to convert the data type

Answer (score 0):

You can change your DataFrame into Numpy array as a workaround:

```
 np.savetxt(savepath, np.array(df).astype(np.int), fmt='%i', delimiter = ',', header= 'PassengerId,Survived', comments='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another solution:

```
df['IntColumnWithNAValues'].fillna(0, inplace=True) #Fill with a value that is out of your range

df['IntColumnWithNAValues'] = df['IntColumnWithNAValues'].astype(int)

df['IntColumnWithNAValues'].replace(0, '', inplace=True)
```

.csv files doesn't differentiate between NA or '' (empty string) as it as a text file, so you get to keep your missing fields while converting non null values to int.

You can do this for every column that you want; If you have lots of columns it might be a problem.