# Pandas Read SQL to CSV - Int conversion

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have data from a local Postgres database that I need to upload to S3 and then copy into Redshift.

To accomplish this, I am using Python Pandas as follows:

```
engine = create_engine(self.engine)
connection = engine.raw_connection()
df = pd.read_sql(<sql string>, connection, coerce_float=False)
df.to_csv(<output fn>, header=True, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

The sql that it executes returns rows of `varchar(255), varchar(255), int, int`. However, since some of these values can be null I run into the [Pandas Caveat about integers and NaN values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092671/python-pandas-output-dataframe-to-csv-with-integers) solves their issue by setting na to an arbitrary int and the astype explicitly as int. They are able to do so because all their columns are of the same datatype. However, I have a mix of varchar(255) and int.

How can I force `df.to_csv(...)` to output my ints as ints (and not floats)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you insert these two lines above `df.to_csv()`?

```
df = df.fillna(<some_int>)
df[[int_col1, int_col2]] = df[[int_col1, int_col2]].astype('int64')
```

Comment: I want nulls to stay nulls. I do not want them to be an arbitrary int. If so, Redshift's copy will insert the arbitrary int as that record's field value.

Comment: What is Redshift's null identifier? If it is like '\N' in SQL, you can convert the column to varchar and replace all null values with '\\N'...

Comment: The Redshift copy command allows for BLANKASNULL and EMPTYASNULL. Fields in redshift cannot have their datatype changed. Rather, you must create a new column of the datatype you want and then do `update <table> set <column> = null where <column> = <arbitrary char>;`. This could work, but I'd really like a less involved solution if one exists. Thank you though! If nothing else better shows up in the next few days, I'll implement this and mark as the solution.

Comment: I am assuming that having int converted to float is a problem as well. I too don't see any other solution apart from what you have said. That doesn't mean some other user might not have a better idea. Poke around a bit, something might pop up.