# Loading dataframe using copy_from from StringIO into Postgresql psycopg

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I cannot seam to figure out how to fix this issue.

My code looks something like

```
import pandas 
import psycopg2
import io
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
#engine works
cursor = engine.raw_connection()

output = io.StringIO()
df.to_csv(output, sep=',', header=False, index=False)
output.seek(0)
contents = output.getvalue()
print(contents)
cursor.copy_from(output, table_name, sep=",", null="NULL")
connection.commit()
```

It seems like my integers are interpreted incorrectly:

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type integer: "180.0" CONTEXT:  COPY athletes, line 1, column height: "180.0"
```

Here is sample of contents:

```
135552,Jan (Johann-) Zybert (Siebert-),M,1908-01-01,NULL,NULL
135553,Galina Ivanovna Zybina (-Fyodorova),F,1931-01-01,168.0,80.0
135554,Bogusaw Zych,M,1952-01-01,182.0,82.0
135556,Bogusaw Stanisaw Zychowicz,M,1961-01-01,189.0,80.0
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Change your datatype to a decimal

Comment: Thank you so much know that I knew that the numbers are floats not int as required by our assignment, I was able to change it the data from the dataframe to ints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Frank Heikens said it had to do with the fields in the database, you could either change them to decimal or as I did it you could also adjust the datatype columns in the dataframe.

[Python pandas: output dataframe to csv with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092671/python-pandas-output-dataframe-to-csv-with-integers)

```
def convert(x):
    try:
        return x.astype(int)
    except:
        return x

df = df.apply(convert)
```

Thanks everyone